# Logging Onto the LDAP directory prior to authentication.

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory

I have successfully used the code below to authenticate users in an LDAP environment for a number of years.    Now, I have a client who wants me to log into to the LDAP directory (it's an Active Directory LDAP environment) prior to authentication and then do the authentication.   In other words, I would pass two sets of credentials to the server, one to gain access to the LDAP directory, and the second to actually do the authentication.  Is there an easy way to modify my existing code to do this?   Are their alternative code patterns that would allow this to be done easily?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;
public class ADAuthenticator {
 private String domain;
  private String ldapHost;
  private String searchBase;

  public ADAuthenticator()
  {
    this.domain = "<your domain>";
    this.ldapHost = "ldap://<your AD controller>";
    this.searchBase = "your AD root e.g. dc=abbl,dc=org";
  }

  public ADAuthenticator(String domain, String host, String dn)
  {
    this.domain = domain;
    this.ldapHost = host;
    this.searchBase = dn;
  }

  public Map authenticate(String user, String pass)
  {
    String returnedAtts[] ={ "sn", "givenName", "mail" };
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";

    //Create the search controls
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

    //Specify the search scope
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);

    LdapContext ctxGC = null;

    try
    {
      ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
      //Search objects in GC using filters
      NamingEnumeration answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
      while (answer.hasMoreElements())
      {
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        Map amap = null;
        if (attrs != null)
        {
          amap = new HashMap();
          NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();
          while (ne.hasMore())
          {
            Attribute attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
            amap.put(attr.getID(), attr.get());
          }
          ne.close();
        }
          return amap;
      }
    }
    catch (NamingException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }
```

}